# C/C++ libraries for compression of 2D array of integers

Tags: c++, c

I have two 2d array of integers. Basically these integers are pixel values of a FITS image. I would like apply leightweight lossless compression techniques like null suppression (SIMD-BP128) etc. on the FITS file.

I want to know what are the libraries available in C/C++, which I can use to apply these compression techniques.

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for has the [LEADTOOLS C/C++ imaging library](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/c-windows) that supports compressing images in different formats, including more than one type of lossless compression. The library supports loading and saving [FITS images](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/main/api/fits-format-fit.html). You can use it to load the uncompressed FITS image, then save it into a different format that uses lossless compression such as PNG, TIFF/LZW or even lossless JPEG (which is a valid but not very common format, since the common JPEG is lossy).

If you would like to try it, there’s a free evaluation [on this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).